# What reason should I have chosen for voting to close this compile error question? Should I have voted to close it at all?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754371/fail-to-build-dlangui-the-cross-platform-gui-for-d-programming-language) that dealt with compiling someone's library.  The question paraphrased the compile error and copied the handful of isolated lines that the compiler pointed to.

The question felt off-topic to me, so I voted to close it.  I didn't really give a good reason, though; I just said that it was a question better suited to the library's issue tracker.

I'm thinking now that it would have been much more helpful (and correct) to say that I voted to close the question because there's not enough information to diagnose the problem.  But I can also see "non-reproducible" working, as well as "unclear what's being asked."

Which close reason makes more sense in this case?  Or should I not have voted to close at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP seems to have identified the problem fairly well, but it's unclear what he wants to do now. He's asking how to fix it but there's not enough information to take a crack at that so really all he can do is pass it back to the library's authors.

I left a comment to that effect and voted to close as 'unclear what you're asking'.